# Подключение телеграмм бота к Heroku Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot, heroku, aiogram

Есть телеграмм бот, написанный на Python/aiogram, раннее использовал базу данных SQLite 3, потом понял, что Heroku поддерживает Postgresql, нужна помощь по установке бота на Heroku Postgres, готов даже заплатить, если нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):

Используйте команду `heroku addons` для проверки подключённого аддона.

Если `heroku-postgresql` не отображается, CLI команда `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:<PLAN_NAME>` добавит аддон.

Бесплатный тариф (PLAN_NAME) - `hobby-dev`

После выполнения команды вы увидите примерно следующее:

> Created postgresql-concave-52656 as DATABASE_URL

Обычно БД становится доступной к работе в течении 5 минут, вы так же можете отслеживать статус с помощью команды `heroku pg:wait`, которая блокируется, пока ваша база данных не будет готова к использованию.

`DATABASE_URL` содержит URL-адрес, который ваше приложение использует для доступа к базе данных.

Вы можете проверить имена и значения переменных конфигурации вашего приложения с помощью `heroku config`

> Значение переменной DATABASE_URL конфигурации вашего приложения может
> измениться в любое время. Вы не должны полагаться на это значение ни
> внутри, ни за пределами вашего приложения Heroku.

На этом этапе создается пустая база данных PostgreSQL. Чтобы заполнить его данными из существующего источника данных, см.[Инструкции](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) по [импорту](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) или следуйте инструкциям для конкретного языка в этой статье, чтобы подключиться из вашего приложения.

Приложения Heroku используют `DATABASE_URL` для обозначения URL-адреса первичной базы данных приложения. Если ваше приложение имеет только одну базу данных, ее URL-адрес автоматически назначается этой переменной конфигурации.

Вы можете совместно использовать одну базу данных Heroku Postgres между несколькими приложениями с помощью `heroku addons:attach`:

```
heroku addons:attach my-originating-app::DATABASE --app sushi
Attaching postgresql-addon-name to sushi... done
Setting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE vars and restarting sushi... done, v11
```

[Чтобы использовать PostgreSQL в качестве базы данных в приложениях Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python), вам необходимо использовать `psycopg2`.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

И используйте этот пакет для подключения `DATABASE_URL` в своем коде.

```
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, мне только не понятно, как мне автоматически в программе менять url для подключения?

Comment: В изначальном вопросе нет упоминания о том, что необходимо меня url автоматически. Опишите сценарий зачем это требуется.

Comment: уже разобрался, в хероку системе есть 2 переменные, там uri на эти базы данных, все получилось через os.environ